# Locations geocoding to province, not country

Tags: google-maps, location

I previously asked a question but since have done much research and am getting more focused on my problem.

I have a locations cck field in a profiles 2 profile. Here, I get users to select just countries (no cities or provinces) and they are geocoded to points and displayed on a user specific map. Many of the countries are not accurate. I have discovered the locations are being geocoded by their province code. Example: the country code is being ignored and it is selecting a province code.

[image: Barbados in Germany]
[image: Here is a partial list of incorrect countries]

I had a problem that Barbados was being displayed in Germany. Barbados has a country code of "BB", but I found that the point was being displayed in Brandenburg Germany, the province code "BB". Every wrong point can be explained this was but 3.

I have the geocoding setup to be at a country level accuracy. I dont think its a config problem and I have yet to find any other people with this problem.

Any ideas on what to do?

Thanks

Comment: If you feel the geocoding is wrong, or you need more options than the module provides you with, it would be more appropriate to ask in the module issue queue. We can't take bug reports/feature requests for contrib modules here I'm afraid

Comment: @Clive as far as I remember in previous question OP started to take the module apart and he already, messed about it's code a bit, and wrote he is willing to fix it on his own, so I'm not sure if it should count as a mere bugreport. It may use some improvements all right, but maybe it might be a valid question.

Comment: @Mołot I still think a discussion about re-writing/fixing a contrib module should be had in the module's issue queue. Having it here isn't really very useful to other users of the module. Don't get me wrong - good question, well researched, usually the sort of thing we love here. But because it's specifically about fixing a contrib module, I would always recommend the conversation happens on Drupal.org

Comment: @Clive Would you agree that best way is to have a bugreport there and small in-development questions here? Greg, consider finding me on Skype. And link bugreport if there is one. I'm interested n getting this done too.

Comment: @Mołot Ideally yeah, but breaking this up into context-less code pieces might be difficult (the issue is part of the worfklow of the module, as I can tell, and extracting meaningful out-of-context functions would probably be confusing). I've got no intention of closing this or anything, just wanted to point out it might be better suited to Drupal.org

Comment: @Clive you may be right. And as you can see I'm not upvoting it as it is now ;)

Comment: Here is the bug report: https://drupal.org/node/2072869

Comment: If there is anything more you'd like me to do I am more than determined to get this working (Although I have not mastered php, I am still more than willing to do my best)

Comment: @Mołot The bug report doesn't seem to be getting any attention. Using cities within the country may be a way to solve my problem. Would there be anyway to use a hook alter and create your own module (Using something similar to 'function location_province_list_xx' in the location.xx.inc file) to make a dropdown list for use when a country is selected in the location module (Using ajax).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not actually with that snippet of code in _google_geocode_flatten(), but is just a result of google's geocoding algorithms.

For example, your search for BB finds 2 results, Brandenburg Germany & Barbados, however google puts the former as the first result, possibly due to popularity of searches or something.

See http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=bb&region=bb&sensor=false

The solution I can see is to also pass in the component param when requesting from google geocoder, which allows you to specify specific parts of the address in addition to the full address string.

See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ComponentFiltering

I have posted a patch back to your issue on drupal.org

Answer (score 0):

Looks like each geocoding service is responsible for 'flattening' the address to a string, so that's where you need to look. The default one included with Location is the Google Geocoder. In its [`_google_geocode_flatten()`](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21location%21geocoding%21google.inc/function/_google_geocode_flatten/7) function you'll find this interesting piece of code (the comment being especially interesting):

```
// @@@ Fix this!
if (substr($location['province'], 0, 3) == $location['country'] . '-') {
  $address .= substr($location['province'], 3);
  watchdog('Location', 'BUG: Country found in province attribute.');
}
else {
  $address .= $location['province'];
}
```

So I'm going to take a guess that's where the problem is.

As for fixing it, I'd strongly recommend liaising with the module maintainers on Drupal.org, as it looks like this is a known bug.

Comment: I have found this snip-it of code in the google.inc function as you stated, as well as the location.inc function location_address2singleline($location = array()) I have also posted a bug report